# how to duplicate values of each row under each for n times?

Tags: scripting

I have daily data which I want to duplicate in to 24 hours data keeping the value the same for the hourly time step. My data looks like:

```
day       Value
01/01/2012  2
01/02/2012  3
```

Then I want the output be:

```
Day   Value
01/01/2012  2
01/01/2012  2
01/01/2012  2
01/01/2012  2
01/01/2012  2
01/01/2012  2
01/01/2012  2
01/01/2012  2
01/01/2012  2
01/01/2012  2
.
.
.

01/02/2012  3
01/02/2012  3
01/02/2012  3
01/02/2012  3
01/02/2012  3
01/02/2012  3
01/02/2012  3
01/02/2012  3
01/02/2012  3
01/02/2012  3
.
.
.
```

i.e. 24 times for each day.

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'NR == 1 {print $0}; NR > 1 {for(i=0;i<24;i++) print $0}' InputFile
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I checked it and works perfect for one File. I have more that 1000 of such files to duplicate.Is there any way I can do all the same time? Thank you

Comment: You can use simple bash loop for do it.

Answer (score 1):

#### Method #1

If you put the above lines into a file called `sample.txt` you can use `tail`, `xargs`, and `printf` to do this:

```
$ cat <(head -1 sample.txt) <(tail -n +2 sample.txt \
    | xargs -I{} printf "{}\n%.0s" {1..25})
```

#### Details

Assuming you have the following type of file.

```
$ more sample.txt 
day       Value
01/01/2012  2
01/02/2012  3
```

The `head` will preserve the header row from `sample.txt`:

```
$ head -1 sample.txt 
day       Value
```

The `tail` does the following:

```
$ tail -n +2 sample.txt
01/01/2012  2
01/02/2012  3
```

The `xargs` takes each line from the file and calls `printf` to print them X number of times, where the range `{1..25}` produces the count.

The `cat <(...) <(...)` puts it all together.

#### Method #2

Similar in form to the first it's slightly different. Instead of using the subshells and the `cat` for the final construction of the output it uses a single subshell chaining the output from the various commands together. It also makes use of a more traditional approach of using a `while` loop to go through each line of the input file, `sample.txt`. It again makes use of the same technique of lopping off the second line and up, using `tail`.

```
$ (head -1 sample.txt; while read i ; do seq 25 \
   | xargs -i -- echo $i ; done < <(tail -n +2 sample.txt))
```

The form is as follows:

```
$ ( ... ; while .... done <(tail ...) )
```

The outer parens act as the `cat` did in the 1st example, putting all the output s together.

#### Multiple files

The OP asked how to modify this solution so that it could be used for processing 1000+ files. Wrapping the block of code form method #1 for example would yield something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.txt; do
  cat <(head -1 $file) <(tail -n +2 $file | xargs -I{} printf "{}\n%.0s" {1..25}) | tee new_$file
done
```

This will loop through all the files named `*.txt` and write them out to files named `new_*.txt`. This can be adapted as needed.

Comment: You removed the first line of input file.

Comment: @Gnouc - yup just noticed that was adding it back in.

Comment: @Sim Thank you for your help. I checked it and works perfect for one File. But,I have more that 1000 of such files to duplicate.Is there any way I can do all the same time? Thank you

Comment: @Abraham - is there any pattern to these 1000 files?

Comment: @Sim, Thank you for helping. It is perfect

Comment: @Abraham - glad to have helped. Thanks for the question. Please mark either my answer or Gnouc's as the accepted answer so others know your issue's been resolved.